# How to print a number as hexadecimal in Zig?

Tags: hex, zig

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() void {
    const foo: u8 = 128;
    std.debug.print("{}\n", .{foo}); // "128"
}
```

The above prints `128` as expected.
How can the value be printed as hexadecimal instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `x` or `X` inside the curly brackets.
There are additional options as well:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() void {
    // Tested with Zig v0.10.1

    const foo: u8 = 26;
    std.debug.print("0x{x}\n", .{foo}); // "0x1a"
    std.debug.print("0x{X}\n", .{foo}); // "0x1A"

    const bar: u16 = 1;
    std.debug.print("0x{x}\n", .{bar}); //     "0x1"
    std.debug.print("0x{x:2}\n", .{bar}); //   "0x 1"
    std.debug.print("0x{x:4}\n", .{bar}); //   "0x   1"
    std.debug.print("0x{x:0>4}\n", .{bar}); // "0x0001"

    const baz: u16 = 43;
    std.debug.print("0x{x:0>4}\n", .{baz}); // "0x002b"
    std.debug.print("0x{X:0>8}\n", .{baz}); // "0x0000002B"

    const qux: u32 = 0x1a2b3c;
    std.debug.print("0x{X:0>2}\n", .{qux}); // "0x1A2B3C" (not cut off)
    std.debug.print("0x{x:0>8}\n", .{qux}); // "0x001a2b3c"
}
```

You can read more about the placeholders at https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/master/lib/std/fmt.zig

Comment: Posted within the same second as the question... How is that possible?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Self-answer is an explicit feature of SO. Read more at https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer